# Constant Static/Crackling/Poping noise coming from speakers

Tags: audio, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, speakers

I've recently built a new computer, see parts here: https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/xQkby4
The  speakers are plugged into the rear aux cable of the desktop and I can hear a constant static ,crackling sound coming from the speakers. If I move the mouse I can hear a higher frequency sound as I move it.
Having searched around I've tried the following:

Problem:

- Plugged speakers into rear aux cable of the desktop (Bad, noise)
  Troubleshooting attempts:

1. speakers into laptop (Good, no noise)

- This suggests to me the speakers on their own are working?

2. earphones into rear aux cable of the desktop (Good, no noise)

- This suggests to me that the rear aux input is working?
- https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00NEYPWGG/

3. unplugged the entire machine so now its only the PSU cable and speakers plugged into the desktop (Bad, noise).
4. I purchased a ground loop noise isolator and used that in between the speakers and my desktop rear aux cable  (Bad, noise)

- https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LYYRT7M
  Drivers:

5. GPU

   I took out my GPU and turned on the computer with just the PSU and speakers in. I could no longer hear the static/crackling/poping sound. The only sound that remained was white noise.

   I put the GPU back in in the, static/crackling/poping came back

   I tried a different GPU the static/crackling/poping came back

   I tried a lower PCI slot and static/crackling/poping came back.

So it looks like I am receiving this interference because I have a GPU installed in my computer.

I have the audio driver installed which can be found on the motherboard website https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MEG-Z490-UNIFY#down-driver&Win10 64  - I hear the noises even before windows boots.

Comment: Just a comment, but trying another pair of speakers (beyond headphones) might be the next step. Because this electrical interaction sounds rather specific to the components you have (GPU/Soundcard/Speakers).

Answer (score 0):

Amplified loudspeakers can pick up, amplify and "detect" high-frequency (radio frequency interference, RFI) signals and make them audible. Place a cell phone near speaker wires, and you might hear an occasional "beep" each time the phone broadcasts a comparatively powerful signal to the tower.

To avoid this issue, isolate the audio output wires from all other signals:

- Route audio wires *away* from  other wires in the case. While it improves accessibility to route and bundle wires in parallel, keep these separate.
- Put small ceramic capacitors (perhaps 0.1 µFd, 25 V or higher rating) across the audio output jack. That small value should not degrade *audio* at all, but will short out RFI.
- You can also put a ceramic capacitor *inside* the amplified speaker input, where the leads enter.
- Make sure the case has RF shielding, i.e. gaskets and other devices to thoroughly contain RFI. Keep it closed in use.

Comment: Using higher quality audio cables might also help, typically there isn’t a difference, but it sounds like there the threshold is barely being reached which is the reason the interference is being heard.  It could also be the GPU, if the GPU has a leaky capacitor, that might be what’s being detected.

Comment: Ive tried 2 different GPU's the static occurs with both. Ive even tried different PCIE slots

Comment: As soon as i disable the GPU/unplug it, i no longer hear the static, but ofcourse i need a GPU in my machine

Comment: Also ive tested just having just the PSU and speaker cables in my machine, and i still heard the static/crackling/pop noises whilst in the bios. If everything else is unplugged im not sure how else i can isolate the wires and whether i should be trying to isolate them or is this a bigger issue with the motherboard /psu ?

Comment: As @Ramhound suggests, you might need a bypass capacitor across the **power** supply connections on the GPU board, and take extra care that the GPU board is *properly grounded*. There may be a number of locations on the board that must contact the mounting rails -- check the installation instructions.

Comment: "Also ive tested just having just the PSU and speaker cables in my machine" - This means you have isolated it down to your PSU.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't think its the GPU, ive tried inserting a spare GPU that worked on my old rig and i could heart static coming from speakers with the old GPU in.

Comment: @Ramhound But i don't understand why taking the GPU out stops the static sound? Do you think i should replace the PSU?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  "you might need a bypass capacitor across the power supply connections on the GPU board, and take extra care that the GPU board is properly grounded."

I really don't understand what you mean by bypass a capacitor. How do i know if my GPU is properly grounded, how can i determine that?

Comment: A "bypass capacitor" shunts, or bypasses, RF to ground.https://www.electronicshub.org/bypass-capacitor-tutorial/